# How to read MMA8542q Accelerometer sensor in Matlab using Raspberry

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi3, accelerometer, i2c

I need help please, I try to read the position [x,y,z ] in matlab, here is my code,

enter code here

```
mypi = raspi;
scanI2CBus(mypi,'i2c-1');
myi2c = i2cdev(mypi,'i2c-1','0x1D');
output-1 = read(myi2c, 8)
```

In my code I have this output

```
enter code here
0  13  248  84  252  254  64  0
```

**My problem here** is all values will be the same even if I change the position of the sensor.(All time the same values).
 **How I can get the position [x,y,z],my sensor is MMA8542q.**

Thank you!

Comment: Had you chance to read a data sheet?

Comment: I have done but I'm a new , I don't understand what I should do, which register I have to read, if you can help me please with x position and I try my self then. Thank you.

Comment: So, what section in the data sheet makes you feel unclear about?
Btw, had you chance to look at the (closest) driver in Linux kernel?